# Adobe air - how to make an air app always run?

Tags: flash, air

I am doing an air application using flash cs5 which on launch will be invisible but still will be active in the background. So when the user clicks anywhere on the desktop or any other place the application should add the objects which the app provides. So my question is when the app is made invisible the desktop is shown and when clicked on desktop it activates the desktop and nothing happens as expected. What should I do in order to get the app working as expected?

If you are not clear about the idea what I just said Please have a look at the video on youtube.. " http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKzsWH0sQHs " its the last app what he shows in the video..

here is my code,

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.NativeWindowInitOptions;

stage.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront;
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

var nwio:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
nwio.transparent = true;
nwio.resizable = false;
nwio.minimizable = false;
nwio.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.NONE;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addThings);

function addThings(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var test:Test = new Test();
    addChild(test);
    test.x = stage.mouseX;
    test.y = stage.mouseY;
}
```

the Test class is the object on stage exported into class.. Please help me.. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where NativeWindowInitOptions are connected to actual window (it must be new opened one). If you want to alter default window, edit application descriptor.